# How to get all fields of a class

Tags: java, reflection

I have two classes with same number of fields and with same field names .
the only different is their field Types.

what I need to do is to get all fields value from one class and put them into the other one .

```
public class PersonA {
    private String name;
    private String family;
    //here AddressDto package is com.test.project.employer
    private AddressDto addressDto;
    //here ContactInfo package is com.test.project.employer
    private List<ContactInfo> contactInfo;
}

public class PersonB {
        private String name;
        private String family;
        //here AddressDto package is com.test.project.customer
        private AddressDto addressDto; 
        //here ContactInfo package is com.test.project.customer
        private List<ContactInfo> contactInfo;
    }
```

there might be other Dtos inside outer Dtos too  or Maps with Custom Dtos , so I need to manage all fields to be checked if there is an other dto inside or not !

what I have done already , works for Java classes and Primitive types like String , BigDecimal , int and ... but not for my application dtos .

here is my code :

```
PersonA personA = new PersonA();
PersonB personB = new PersonB();

Field[] aFields = personA.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

for (Field field : aFields){
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Field bField= personB.getClass().getDeclaredField(field.getName());
    bField.setAccessible(true);
    Object value = field.get(personA);
    bField.set(personB, value);
}
```

what I am thinking of is to write it in recursive form.
Is there any solution for my problem ?

Comment: Let's take a step back here and figure out what the problem actually is. Why do you want to do it like this? Do you have to use reflection?

Comment: Note : Dozer already does this so unless you do it for learning purpose, you should consider using dozer : https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer

Comment: Theoretically interesting point but do you realize that you can have two instances of the same class personA and a copy() method?

Comment: @Veliko I think that the aim is to convert an entity to a dto. For this purpose, it would make sense to do that.

Comment: @nbokmans yes I have to use Reflection , the problem is that my project is at the middle of 2 projects , one of them is soap webservice and the other one is RMI.
at first RMI service get Invoked and I have to get RMI RequestDto by reflection and put all the fields to SOAP requestDto and then Call the Service from webservice .

Comment: @Veliko I am using Aspect to get these two classes , They are not same Classes to copy , they just have same fileds .

Comment: try using dozer, as suggested above. it makes sense in your case.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Thank you Arnaud , dozer helped me a lot